# Behat login form always triggers invalid credentials

Tags: symfony, selenium, tdd, behat, mink

I am trying to make a login verification step with Behat.
I am cleaning the database and execute a Fixture loader before the tests start so the users are in the database (I checked this and it is correct).
For some reason after the inputs are filled (with correct data) submit fails with invalid credentials. If I enter the data again manually (username and password) on the same open session of the opened browser it works.
**See updates at the bottom for a solution**

> feature

```
Feature: Login to application
  In order to access admin area
  I need to login as an administrator

  @javascript
  Scenario Outline: Login as <administrator>
    When I am logged in as an administrator with <administrator> credentials
    Then I wait for "10" seconds
...

    Examples:
      | administrator |
      | admin         |
```

> LoginContext

```
use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\Context\PageObjectContext;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;

require_once __DIR__.'/Resources/Users/ymlParser/UserCredentialsParser.php';

/**
 * Class LoginContext
 */
class LoginContext extends PageObjectContext implements Context
{

    /**
     * @param $administrator
     *
     * @When /^I am logged in as an administrator with ([^"]*) credentials$/
     */
    public function iAmLoggedInAsAnAdministrator($administrator)
    {
        $this->getPage('Login Page')->open();
        $this->getPage('Login Page')->enterLoginDetails(UserCredentialsParser::load($administrator));
        $this->getPage('Login Page')->submitLoginForm();

        //$this->getPage('Login Page')->showLoginSuccessful();
        //$this->getPage('Login Page')->isLoggedInUserAdmin(true);
    }
}
```

> UserCredentialParser

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;

/**
 * Class UserCredentialsParser
 */
class UserCredentialsParser
{    
    /**
     * @param $fileName
     *
     * @return null|stdClass
     */
    public static function load($fileName)
    {
        $oUser    = null;
        $filePath = __DIR__.'/../usersCredentials/'.$fileName.'.yml';

        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            try {
                $userData = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($filePath));

                $oUser           = new stdClass();
                $oUser->username = $userData['username'];
                $oUser->password = $userData['password'];
            } catch (ParseException $e) {
                printf("Unable to parse YAML string %s", $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $oUser;
    }
}
```

> Login Page

```
namespace Page;

use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Page;

/**
 * Class LoginPage
 * @package Page
 */
class LoginPage extends Page
{
    protected $path = '/login';

    /**
     * @param $oUser
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function enterLoginDetails($oUser)
    {
        return $this->getElement('Login Form')->enterLoginDetails($oUser);
    }

    /**
     * Submit registration form
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function submitLoginForm()
    {
        return $this->getElement('Login Form')->submitLoginForm();
    }    
}
```

> Login Form

```
namespace Page\Element;

use SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\PageObject\Element;

/**
 * Class LoginForm
 * @package Page\Element
 */
class LoginForm extends Element
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $selector = 'form';

    /**
     * Fill up the login form
     *
     * @param $oUser
     */
    public function enterLoginDetails($oUser)
    {
        $this->fillField('_username', $oUser->username);
        $this->fillField('_password', $oUser->password);
    }

    /**
     * Submit registration form button
     */
    public function submitLoginForm()
    {
        $this->pressButton('_submit');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The problem was that for any kind of free text there was a tab inserted after the text in the input boxes (probably by the driver - in my case chrome). When i switched to Firefox it worked without any problem and no extra white spaces were added.

Comment: A var_dump/echo in enterLoginDetails shows the right credentials? If the credentials are filled ok and the right submit button is pressed maybe you have some delay related to the database, try using a 10 seconds wait before login step and see if is the same. Also make sure you set the right credential in the database, double check to be sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: No... i just noticed it's adding an extra space (or tab) after the password... Now I am not sure how to get that out ... trim seems to have no effect...

Comment: I think you should follow and see where and why is adding this.Also check the yml for the admin.As a temporary alternative you can try str_replace(' ', '', $string);

Comment: funny is even if i add a normal string i have the same situation ...

Comment: If you replaced $oUser->password from enterLoginDetails with a string and you have the same issue then fillField is not working ok since manual is working or maybe the environment adds this somehow.

Comment: Hm... I downloaded last version of selenium and it seems now it works ... Strange.

Comment: You can add this as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for any kind of free text there was a tab inserted after the text in the input boxes (probably by the driver - in my case chrome). When i switched to Firefox it worked without any problem and no extra white spaces were added.

**UPDATE**: As for *2nd November 2016* I updated to the latest CHROME driver and it seems it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated chrome-driver to the newest version currently at 2.24 and it fixed the problem for me.